# Disable Touchpad when Typing

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I have a Windows 10 laptop without a Synaptics Device. How can I disable the touchpad when typing on keyboard, either by Windows methods or other software?

Answer (score 0):

Is your device a Precision Touchpad?

If yes, you can go to Settings -> Devices -> Touchpad
In Touchpad Sensitivity dropdown, select the option "Low Sensitive". (Medium is default)

*Note: This option is just a timeout for touchpad use during typing.*